# Why does var not work on DataGridViewSelectedRowCollectoin

Tags: c#, winforms, collections, var

I am interestend in the reason why the var keyword does not work properlyin a foreach-loop on the DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection.

ex1:

```
var selectedRows = MyDataGridView.SelectedRows;
foreach (var row in selectedRows)
        { 
            var foo = row.DataBoundItem;
            _bindingSource.Remove(foo);
        }
```

ex1 the type of 'row' is object.
Why is it not of type 'DataGridViewRow'

ex2 works perfectly:

```
var selectedRows = MyDataGridView.SelectedRows;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in selectedRows)
        { 
            var foo = row.DataBoundItem;
            _bindingSource.Remove(foo);
        }
```

also if I access the item of the collection directly it works:

```
var selectedRows = MyDataGridView.SelectedRows;
var foo = selectedRows[0];
var bar = foo.GetType().Name; // bar == DataGridViewRow
```

I am interested in the reason why this happens.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to do `selectedRows[0].DataBoundItem;` in ex2? Because its not a 'fair' comparison atm :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [DataGridView.SelectedRows Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedrows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns a [DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewselectedrowcollection(v=vs.110).aspx).  The type declaration for DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection class is:

```
public class DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection : BaseCollection, 
    IList, ICollection, IEnumerable
```

Notice that the class implements `IEnumerable`, but not `IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow>`. The [IEnumerator.Current Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.current(v=vs.110).aspx) that is returned as the item of a `foreach` loop is of type `System.Object`.  Therefore, the IDE/compiler is assigning `var row` an object type and technically the type inference is working as specified.

The reason `var foo = selectedRows[0];` *works*, is that the [DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection.Item Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewselectedrowcollection.item(v=vs.110).aspx) returned by the C# indexer is typed as a DataGridViewRow, so the type inference picks that up.

Comment: And as workaround if you want loop selected rows you can cast collection to collection of `DataGridViewRow` - `foreach(var row in dataGridView.SelectedRows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()) ...`